# How can I connect style.css to base.html django?

Tags: css, django

Im trying to make style.css file work but i cant figure out what am i doing bad.
I added
to settings: (i have tried many paths(i tried every way of absolute path))

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/polls'),
```

]

to base.html:

```
{% load static %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}" />
```

my structure:

```
PizzaPortal  
 -PizzaPortal
  -settings.py 
 -polls
  -static
     -polls
        -style.css
  -templates
```

Answer (score 0):

refer first to :

- [Writing your first Django app, part 6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial06/)
- [Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/polls'),
]
```

you don't need to add `static/polls` to `STATICFILES_DIRS`, because:

> One of the defaults is **AppDirectoriesFinder** which looks for a **static** sub directory in **each of the INSTALLED_APPS**, like the one in polls we just created

and

> Django’s **STATICFILES_FINDERS** setting contains a **list of finders** that know how to discover **static files from various sources**.

in this case, your project could have a **global** `static` folder under the root folder which holds app-independent static files that will be loaded for each page for e.g: loading `bootstrap` lib via `cdn` or `jquery` lib ..

to serve static files during **development**, you need add some lines of settings if missing:

- in `settings.py`

```
# "static" is located under the root folder of your project
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
)
```

- and in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [

    [..]

]

# DEBUG = True
if settings.DEBUG:

    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```